# Analytic formula for an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'm working on a physics problem which needs the analytic formula for the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{V_1}\int_{0}^{V_2} \frac{4 p^4}{\cos(2ap/\hbar)\left(2p^2z_1z_2-\frac{z_1^2z_2^2}{2}\right)+p^2(z_1^2+z_2^2)+\frac{1}{2}z_1^2z_2^2-\sin(2ap/\hbar)pz_1z_2(z_1+z_2)+4p^4}dz_1dz_2 $$

the denominator is symmetric in $z_1$ and $z_2$ so I think there may exist an analytic formula for it. Mathematica is able to work out one integral and gives me something in terms of $\arctan$ but it fails to do the second. The first indefinite integral (dropping the $\hbar$) evaluates to this:

$$-\frac{4 p^3 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{p \left(-z_1 \sin (a p)-z_2 \sin (a
   p)+2 p \cos (a p)\right)}{p \left(z_2 \cos (a p)+2 p \sin (a
   p)\right)+z_1 \left(p \cos (a p)-z_2 \sin (a p)\right)}\right)}{z_2^2
   \sin ^2(a p)-p z_2 \sin (2 a p)+2 p^2}$$

Is there any possible substitution or coordinate transformation to work this out?

Comment: Using Mathematica, I get a different indefinite integral for the inner integral. It should have $\hbar$ in there as well.

Comment: Yes, the inner integral I put there did not include $\hbar$ because I made the replacement $a/\hbar\to a$. The key point is how do we deal with the inverse tangent integral, or is there any tricks from complex analysis or something that we can use?

Comment: @Andrew What can you tell us about the ranges of the four parameters $a,p,V_1,V_2$? Are they all positive real numbers?

Comment: @DavidH Yes, a and p are positive and real, so are $V_1$ and $V_2$. In fact this formula represents the transmission coeffcient of a particle with a double dirac delta barrier, $a$ represents the distance between the two delta potentials, and $p$ is the momentum of the incoming particle, so they have to be real & positive.

Comment: @Andrew We can at least eliminate some of the clutter in your integral using scaling arguments. It can be shown that $\mathcal{I}{\left(p,a,V_{1},V_{2}\right)}=p^{2}\mathcal{I}{\left(1,pa,\frac{V_{1}}{p},\frac{V_{2}}{p}\right)}$. So without loss of generality, we only need to solve the $p=1$ case.

Comment: @DavidH Yes, that would make the integrand looks simpler. Now it looks like (after $p\to1$): $$\frac{4}{z_1^2 \left(z_2 \sin (a) \left(z_2 \sin (a)-2 \cos
   (a)\right)+1\right)+2 z_2 z_1 \left(\cos (2 a)-z_2 \sin (a) \cos
   (a)\right)+z_2^2+4}$$. The problem is how do we proceed?

Comment: The form of the denominator in the integrand suggests a coordinate transformation like $\left(\frac{z_1+z_2}{2},\sqrt{z_1z_2}\right)=\left(x,y\right)\implies\left(z_1,z_2\right)=\left(x\pm\sqrt{x^{2}-y^{2}},x\mp\sqrt{x^{2}-y^{2}}\right)$ might be helpful, at least in the special case $V_1=V_2$. Still trying to decide if this substitution is more trouble than it's worth in the case $V_1\neq V_2$....

Comment: @DavidH Thank you for the efforts. So does this substitution work when $V_1=V_2$?